# C++ WAVE file reader: library-like structure, safety, readability

Tags: c++, c++11, library, audio

**Introduction**

I have released a small a [WAVE file reader](https://github.com/billguastalla/wavereader) with a mutex/lock-based caching mechanism, as a header-only library. The general purpose of the library is to read WAVE files into floating points, in a way that handles repeated sequential requests for audio data without hanging on disk reads.

I am looking for some criticism of the code but also of the structure of the project.

- Is there anything unsafe about the code, or is there any misuse of language constructs?
- Does the project provide everything you would expect from a public-facing library?

**Code**

````cpp
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <set>


constexpr size_t WAV_HEADER_DEFAULT_SIZE = 44u;
//! Wave header
/*!
 Reads and stores the wave header in the same way it appears in the WAV file.
*/
struct WAV_HEADER
{
    /*!
    * Read the first 44 bytes of the input stream into the header.
    */
    bool read(std::istream& s)
    {
        if (s.good())
        {
            s.seekg(0u);
            s.read(&m_0_headerChunkID[0], 4);
            s.read((char*)&m_4_chunkSize, 4);
            s.read(&m_8_format[0], 4);
            s.read(&m_12_subchunk1ID[0], 4);
            s.read((char*)&m_16_subchunk1Size, 4);
            s.read((char*)&m_20_audioFormat, 2);
            s.read((char*)&m_22_numChannels, 2);
            s.read((char*)&m_24_sampleRate, 4);
            s.read((char*)&m_28_byteRate, 4);
            s.read((char*)&m_32_bytesPerBlock, 2);
            s.read((char*)&m_34_bitsPerSample, 2);
            s.read(&m_36_dataSubchunkID[0], 4);
            s.read((char*)&m_40_dataSubchunkSize, 4);
        }
        return s.good();
    }
    /*!
    * Checks whether the header is in a format that can be read by waveread
    */
    bool valid() const
    {
        return (std::string{ &m_0_headerChunkID[0],4u } == std::string{ "RIFF" }) && // RIFF 
            std::string{ &m_8_format[0],4u } == std::string{ "WAVE" } && // WAVE format
            m_16_subchunk1Size == 16 &&// PCM, with no extra parameters in file
            m_20_audioFormat == 1 && // uncompressed
            m_32_bytesPerBlock == (m_22_numChannels * (m_34_bitsPerSample / 8)) && // block align matches # channels and bit depth
            (
                (m_34_bitsPerSample == 8) ||
                (m_34_bitsPerSample == 16) ||
                (m_34_bitsPerSample == 24) ||
                (m_34_bitsPerSample == 32) // available bit depths
                );
    }
    /*!
    * Clear all data in the header setting values to 0 or "nil\0"
    */
    void clear()
    {
        auto cpy = [](char from[4], char to[4]) // since strcpy is deprecated on windows and strcpy_s absent on *nix.
        {
            for (size_t i{ 0u }; i < 4u; ++i)
                to[i] = from[i];
        };
        char none[4]{ "nil" };
        cpy(none, m_0_headerChunkID);
        m_4_chunkSize = 0;
        cpy(none, m_8_format);
        cpy(none, m_12_subchunk1ID);
        m_16_subchunk1Size = 0;
        m_20_audioFormat = 0;
        m_22_numChannels = 0;
        m_24_sampleRate = 0;
        m_28_byteRate = 0;
        m_32_bytesPerBlock = 0;
        m_34_bitsPerSample = 0;
        cpy(none, m_36_dataSubchunkID);
        m_40_dataSubchunkSize = 0;
    }
    /*!
    * Samples per channel
    */
    int samples() const { return (m_40_dataSubchunkSize / ((m_22_numChannels * m_34_bitsPerSample) / 8)); }

    char m_0_headerChunkID[4]; /*!< Header chunk ID */
    int32_t m_4_chunkSize; /*!< Chunk size*/
    char m_8_format[4]; /*!< Format */

    char m_12_subchunk1ID[4]; /*!< Subchunk ID */
    int16_t m_16_subchunk1Size; /*!< Subchunk size*/

    int16_t m_20_audioFormat; /*!< Audio format */
    int16_t m_22_numChannels; /*!< Number of channels*/
    int32_t m_24_sampleRate; /*!< Sample rate of a single channel */
    int32_t m_28_byteRate; /*!< Number of bytes per sample*/
    int16_t m_32_bytesPerBlock; /*!< Number of bytes per block (where a block is a single sample from each channel)*/
    int16_t m_34_bitsPerSample; /*!< Bits per sample */

    char m_36_dataSubchunkID[4]; /*!< Detailed description after the member */
    int32_t m_40_dataSubchunkSize; /*!< Detailed description after the member */
};
static_assert(sizeof(WAV_HEADER) == WAV_HEADER_DEFAULT_SIZE, "WAV File header is not the expected size.");

//! Wave reader
/*!
  Reads audio from an input stream.
*/
class Waveread
{
public:
    //! Constructor
    /*!
    * \param stream the input stream
    * \param cacheSize the size of the cache. This should usually be a reasonable multiple of the size of the set of samples you expect to read each time you call audio().
    * \param cacheExtensionThreshold Within interval [0,1]. When a caller gets audio, how far into the cache should the caller go before the cache is triggered to be extended?
    */
    Waveread(
        std::unique_ptr<std::istream>&& stream,
        size_t cacheSize = 1048576u,
        double cacheExtensionThreshold = 0.5
    )
        :
        m_stream{ stream.release() },
        m_header{},
        m_data{},
        m_dataMutex{},
        m_cachePos{ 0u },
        m_opened{ false },
        m_cacheSize{ cacheSize }, // 1MB == 1048576u
        m_cacheExtensionThreshold{ cacheExtensionThreshold }
    {
        if (m_cacheExtensionThreshold < 0.0)
            m_cacheExtensionThreshold = 0.0;
        else if (m_cacheExtensionThreshold > 1.0)
            m_cacheExtensionThreshold = 1.0;

        m_header.clear();
    }

    Waveread(const Waveread&) = delete;
    Waveread& operator=(const Waveread&) = delete;

    //! Move Constructor
    /*!
    * \param other  Another waveread object. The move constructor enables the placement of waveread objects in containers using std::move().
    *               For instance you can do:
    *               Waveread a{stream};
    *               std::vector<Waveread> readers;
    *               readers.push_back(std::move(a))
    *               a is now unusable, but the vector now contains the wavereader.
    */
    Waveread(Waveread&& other) noexcept
        :
        m_stream{ },
        m_header{ },
        m_data{ },
        m_dataMutex{},
        m_cachePos{ other.m_cachePos },
        m_opened{ other.m_opened },
        m_cacheSize{ other.m_cacheSize },
        m_cacheExtensionThreshold{ other.m_cacheExtensionThreshold }
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l{ other.m_dataMutex };
        m_data = other.m_data;
        m_header = other.m_header;
        m_stream.reset(other.m_stream.release());
    }
    //! Reset
    /*!
    * Resets the wavereader, clearing all data.
    * \param stream a new std::istream to read a wave file from.
    */
    void reset(std::unique_ptr<std::istream>&& stream)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{ m_dataMutex };
        m_stream = std::move(stream);
        m_data.clear();
        m_header.clear();
        m_cachePos = 0u;
        m_opened = false;
    }
    //! Open
    /*!
    * Loads the wave header from file, and fills the cache from the start.
    */
    bool open()
    {
        if (!m_opened)
        {
            m_header.read(*m_stream.operator->());
            if (m_header.valid())
            {
                m_opened = true;
                load(0u, m_cacheSize);
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false; // we couldn't open it
        }
        return true; // we didn't open it, but it was already opened.
    }
    //! Close
    /*!
    * Closes the wavereader.
    */
    void close()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{ m_dataMutex };
        m_stream->seekg(0u);
        m_data.clear();
        m_header.clear();
        m_cachePos = 0u;
        m_opened = false;
    }
    //! Audio
    /*!
    * Get interleaved floating point audio samples in the interval (-1.f,1.f).
    * \param startSample index of first sample desired
    * \param sampleCount number of samples needed including first sample
    * \param channels Which channels would you like to retrieve. Zero-indexed. If channels are out of bounds, then their modulus with the channel count will be taken. This means if you ask for channels {0,1} from a mono file, you will retrieve two copies of the mono channel, interleaved.
    * \param stride for each channel, when getting samples, skip every n samples where n == stride.
    * \param interleaved determines how samples are ordered: true provides {C1S1, C2S1, ..., CMS1, C1S2, C2S2, ..., CMS2} false provides {C1S1, C1S2, ..., C1SN, C2S1, C2S2, ..., C2S2, ...}
    */
    std::vector<float> audio(
        size_t startSample, 
        size_t sampleCount, 
        std::set<int> channels = std::set<int>{ 0,1 }, 
        size_t stride = 0u, 
        bool interleaved = true
    )
    {
        if (!open())
            return std::vector<float>{};

        size_t startSample_ch_bit{ startSample * m_header.m_32_bytesPerBlock };
        size_t sampleCount_ch_bit{ sampleCount * m_header.m_32_bytesPerBlock };

        if ((startSample_ch_bit + sampleCount_ch_bit) >= (size_t)m_header.m_40_dataSubchunkSize)    // case1: out of bounds of file
        {
            if (startSample_ch_bit >= (size_t)m_header.m_40_dataSubchunkSize)                       // case1A: read starts out of bounds
                return std::vector<float>{};
            else                                                                                    // case1B: read starts within bounds, ends out of bounds
            {
                load(startSample_ch_bit, m_header.m_40_dataSubchunkSize - startSample_ch_bit);
                return samples(0u, m_header.m_40_dataSubchunkSize - startSample_ch_bit, channels, stride, interleaved);
            }
        }
        else if (startSample_ch_bit >= m_cachePos &&
            (startSample_ch_bit + sampleCount_ch_bit) <= (m_cachePos + m_data.size()))              // case2: within cache
        {
            std::vector<float> result{ samples(startSample_ch_bit - m_cachePos, sampleCount_ch_bit, channels, stride,interleaved) };
            if (startSample_ch_bit > (m_cachePos + (size_t)(m_data.size() * m_cacheExtensionThreshold)))                    // case2A: approaching end of cache
            {
                std::thread extendBuffer{ &Waveread::load,this,m_cachePos + (size_t)(m_cacheSize * m_cacheExtensionThreshold), m_cacheSize };
                extendBuffer.detach();
            }
            return result;
        }
        else                                                                                        // case3: within file, outside of cache
        {
            if (load(startSample_ch_bit, m_cacheSize > sampleCount_ch_bit ? m_cacheSize : sampleCount_ch_bit)) // load samplecount or cachesize, whichever is greater.
                return samples(0u, sampleCount_ch_bit, channels, stride, interleaved);
            else
                return std::vector<float>{};
        }
    }

    //! Get header file
    const WAV_HEADER& header() const { return m_header; }
    //! Get size of cache
    const size_t& cacheSize() const { return m_cacheSize; }
    //! Get start position of cache
    const size_t& cachePos() const { return m_cachePos; }
    //! Has the file been opened
    const bool& opened() const { return m_opened; }
    //! Get cache extension threshold: this is the fraction of the cache that is read before it is extended.
    const double& cacheExtensionThreshold() const { return m_cacheExtensionThreshold; }


    //! Set cache extension threshold. Does not extend the cache until audio() has been called. Function will halt until the last load operation has finished.
    void setCacheExtensionThreshold(const double& cacheExtensionThreshold)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l{ m_dataMutex };
        m_cacheExtensionThreshold = cacheExtensionThreshold;
    }
    //! Set cache size. Does not extend the cache until audio() has been called. Function will halt until the last load operation has finished.
    void setCacheSize(const size_t& csize)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l{ m_dataMutex };
        m_cacheSize = csize;
    }
private:
    //! Load data into the cache
    bool load(size_t pos, size_t size) // method will offset read by header size
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{ m_dataMutex };
        size_t truncatedSize{ (pos + size) < (size_t)m_header.m_40_dataSubchunkSize
            ? size : (size_t)m_header.m_40_dataSubchunkSize - pos };
        if (pos < (size_t)m_header.m_40_dataSubchunkSize)
        {
            m_stream->seekg(((std::streampos)pos + (std::streampos)sizeof(WAV_HEADER))); // add header size
            m_data.resize(truncatedSize);
            if (m_stream->good())
            {
                m_stream->read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&m_data[0]), truncatedSize);
                m_cachePos = pos;
                m_stream->clear(std::iostream::eofbit);
                return m_stream->good();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    //! Transform cached bytes into floats.
    /*!
    * \param posInCache
    * \param size
    * \param channels
    * \param stride
    * \param interleaved
    */
    std::vector<float> samples(
        size_t posInCache,
        size_t size,
        std::set<int> channels = std::set<int>{},
        size_t stride = 0u,
        bool interleaved = true) // posInCache is pos relative to cachepos.
    {
        std::vector<float> result{};
        if (
            (posInCache + size) <= m_data.size() &&         // if caller is not overshooting the cache
            !channels.empty()                               // if caller has provided channels
            )
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{ m_dataMutex };
            size_t bpc{ m_header.m_32_bytesPerBlock / (size_t)m_header.m_22_numChannels }; // bytes per channel

            if (interleaved)
                switch (m_header.m_34_bitsPerSample)
                {
                case 8: // unsigned 8-bit
                    for (size_t i{ posInCache }; i < (posInCache + size); i += (m_header.m_32_bytesPerBlock * (1u + stride)))
                    {
                        for (auto ch : channels)
                        {
                            // NOTE: (a) see narrow_cast<T>(var) (b) addition defined in C++ as: T operator+(const T &a, const T2 &b);
                            // EXCEPTIONS: Integer types smaller than int are promoted when an operation is performed on them.
                            size_t cho{ (ch % m_header.m_22_numChannels) * bpc };
                            result.emplace_back((float)
                                (m_data[i + cho] - 128)  // unsigned, so offset by 2^7
                                / (128.f)); // divide by 2^7
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 16: // signed 16-bit
                    for (size_t i{ posInCache }; i < (posInCache + size); i += (m_header.m_32_bytesPerBlock * (1u + stride)))
                    {
                        for (auto ch : channels)
                        {
                            size_t cho{ (ch % m_header.m_22_numChannels) * bpc };
                            result.emplace_back((float)
                                ((m_data[i + cho]) |
                                    (m_data[i + 1u + cho] << 8))
                                / (32768.f)); // divide by 2^15
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 24: // signed 24-bit
                    for (size_t i{ posInCache }; i < (posInCache + size); i += (m_header.m_32_bytesPerBlock * (1u + stride)))
                    {
                        for (auto ch : channels)
                        {
                            size_t cho{ (ch % m_header.m_22_numChannels) * bpc };
                            // 24-bit is different to others: put the value into a 32-bit int with zeros at the (LSB) end
                            result.emplace_back((float)
                                ((m_data[i + cho] << 8) |
                                    (m_data[i + 1u + cho] << 16) |
                                    (m_data[i + 2u + cho] << 24))
                                / (2147483648.f)); // divide by 2^31
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 32: // signed 32-bit
                    for (size_t i{ posInCache }; i < (posInCache + size); i += (m_header.m_32_bytesPerBlock * (1u + stride)))
                    {
                        for (auto ch : channels)
                        {
                            size_t cho{ (ch % m_header.m_22_numChannels) * bpc };
                            result.emplace_back((float)
                                (m_data[i + cho] |
                                    (m_data[i + 1u + cho] << 8) |
                                    (m_data[i + 2u + cho] << 16) |
                                    (m_data[i + 3u + cho] << 24))
                                / (2147483648.f));  // signed, so divide by 2^31
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            else
                switch (m_header.m_34_bitsPerSample)
                {
                case 8: // unsigned 8-bit
                    for (auto ch : channels)
                    {
                        size_t cho{ (ch % m_header.m_22_numChannels) * bpc };
                        for (size_t i{ posInCache }; i < (posInCache + size); i += (m_header.m_32_bytesPerBlock * (1u + stride)))
                        {
                            // NOTE: (a) see narrow_cast<T>(var) (b) addition defined in C++ as: T operator+(const T &a, const T2 &b);
                            // EXCEPTIONS: Integer types smaller than int are promoted when an operation is performed on them.
                            result.emplace_back((float)
                                (m_data[i + cho] - 128)  // unsigned, so offset by 2^7
                                / (128.f)); // divide by 2^7
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 16: // signed 16-bit
                    for (auto ch : channels)
                    {
                        size_t cho{ (ch % m_header.m_22_numChannels) * bpc };
                        for (size_t i{ posInCache }; i < (posInCache + size); i += (m_header.m_32_bytesPerBlock * (1u + stride)))
                        {
                            result.emplace_back((float)
                                ((m_data[i + cho]) |
                                    (m_data[i + 1u + cho] << 8))
                                / (32768.f)); // divide by 2^15
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 24: // signed 24-bit
                    for (auto ch : channels)
                    {
                        size_t cho{ (ch % m_header.m_22_numChannels) * bpc };
                        for (size_t i{ posInCache }; i < (posInCache + size); i += (m_header.m_32_bytesPerBlock * (1u + stride)))
                        {
                            // 24-bit is different to others: put the value into a 32-bit int with zeros at the (LSB) end
                            result.emplace_back((float)
                                ((m_data[i + cho] << 8) |
                                    (m_data[i + 1u + cho] << 16) |
                                    (m_data[i + 2u + cho] << 24))
                                / (2147483648.f)); // divide by 2^31
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 32: // signed 32-bit
                    for (auto ch : channels)
                    {
                        size_t cho{ (ch % m_header.m_22_numChannels) * bpc };
                        for (size_t i{ posInCache }; i < (posInCache + size); i += (m_header.m_32_bytesPerBlock * (1u + stride)))
                        {
                            result.emplace_back((float)
                                (m_data[i + cho] |
                                    (m_data[i + 1u + cho] << 8) |
                                    (m_data[i + 2u + cho] << 16) |
                                    (m_data[i + 3u + cho] << 24))
                                / (2147483648.f));  // signed, so divide by 2^31
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
        }
        return result;
    }

    bool m_opened; /*!< Has the file been opened */
    std::unique_ptr<std::istream> m_stream; /*!< Input stream */

    WAV_HEADER m_header; /*!< Holds structure of header when opened, used in subsequent operations. */
    std::vector<uint8_t> m_data;/*!< Cached data holding part of the data chunk of the WAV file. */
    std::mutex m_dataMutex; /*!< Mutex to lock data when buffer is being extended */
    size_t m_cachePos; /*!< At what point, from the start of the data chunk (i.e. cachePos == idx - 44u), does the cached data in m_data begin at. */
    size_t m_cacheSize; /*!< How big should the cache (all channels) be in bytes */
    double m_cacheExtensionThreshold; /*!< Within interval [0,1]. When a caller gets audio, how far into the cache should the caller go before the cache is triggered to be extended? */
};
```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Ensure correct order of constructor member initializers

My compiler warns me that in the constructors of `Waveread`, `m_cachePos` and `m_opened` are initialized in the wrong order. The order of the constructor initializer list should match the order in which the member variables are declared, otherwise they might be initialized in a different order than you specify, which could be a problem if they depend on each other in some way.

I would also prefer using default member initializers to initialize those member variables that don't depend on the arguments passed to the constructors. So for example:

```
Waveread(
    std::unique_ptr<std::istream>&& stream,
    size_t cacheSize = 1048576u,
    double cacheExtensionThreshold = 0.5
):
    m_stream{ stream.release() },
    m_cacheSize{ cacheSize},
    m_cacheExtensionThreshold{ cacheExtensionThreshold }
{
    ...
}

...

private:
    bool m_opened{};
    std::unique_ptr<std::istream> m_stream;
    WAV_HEADER m_header{};
    std::vector<uint8_t> m_data{};
    std::mutex m_dataMutex{};
    size_t m_cachePos{};
    size_t m_cacheSize;
    double m_cacheExtensionThreshold;
};
```

## Are you sure your mutexes are locked correctly?

If you really want multiple threads to be able to access the same instance of `class Wavereader`, then you better be prepared for them to access the instance at the same time in the most inconvenient places. For example, what happens if two members call `open()` simultaneously? It might happen that both see that `m_opened` is `false`, then they both call `m_header.read(...)`, and likely one of them will read the actual header, the other will read data after right after the header. In what order will `m_header.valid()` be called? When will `m_opened = true` be set? There are many combinations, there's at least one where `m_opened()` will be set to `true` and the function will return `true`, but the values in `m_header` will be garbage.

Either always lock the mutex when doing anything with member variables, or don't have any mutex in your class and leave it up to the callers to handle concurrent access.

## Do you really need to cache yourself?

> The general purpose of the library is to read WAVE files into floating points, in a way that handles repeated sequential requests for audio data without hanging on disk reads.

Virtually all operating systems that you run on desktop computers and servers already have sophisticated cache mechanisms to handle repeated access to the same data on disks. So you are duplicating what the OS already does for you.

If you do lots of small reads, then there is some virtue in doing caching in your code, because it will avoid the overhead of system calls. However, if this is a concern, then it is probably even better to use [memory-mapping](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) to map the whole WAV file into memory.

## Avoid repetition

Whenever you are repeating the same thing twice or more times, you should immediately start to find some way to avoid the repetition. This can be done by using `for`-loops or creating functions, or perhaps reorganizing the code a bit.

In `audio()`, there are three cases being handled separately, but I think this can be simplified by first checking how much data has to be loaded in the cache, then convert `startSample` into the correct offset into the cache, and once that is done, you can do a single `return samples(...)` statement:

```
std::vector<float> audio(...) {
    ...
    size_t offset;
    bool load_ok;

    if (/* out of bounds */) {
        load_ok = load(startSample_ch_bit, m_header.m_40_dataSubchunkSize - startSample_ch_bit);
        offset = 0;
    } else if (/* within cache */) {
        load_ok = true; // Everything has already been loaded
        offset = startSample_ch_bit - m_cachePos;
    } else /* within file, outside cache */ {
        load_ok = load(startSample_ch_bit, m_cacheSize > sampleCount_ch_bit ? m_cacheSize : sampleCount_ch_bit));
        offset = 0;
    }

    if (load_ok)
        return samples(offset, sampleCount_ch_bit, channels, stride, interleaved);
    else
        return {};
}
```

In `samples()`, you have a lot of repetition handling the different sample formats. Try to create a generic function that can convert arbitrarily sized integers. Let the compiler worry about optimizing it. Then just write the code to handle the different ways of channel interleaving. For example:

```
static float convert_sample(const uint8_t *data, size_t len) {
    // Initialize a 32-bit integer with ones or zero bits,
    // depending on whether we need to sign-extend the input data
    int32_t value;

    if (len > 1 && data[len - 1] & 0x80)
        value = -1;
    else
        value = 0;
    
    // Copy the input data into value, assuming everything is little-endian    
    memcpy(&value, data, len);

    // Return it as a float scaled between -1.0 and 1.0
    return static_cast<float>(value) / (1 << (len * 8 - 1)) - (len > 1 ? 0 : 0.5);
}

...

std::vector<float> samples() {
    ...
    const size_t sample_len = header.m_34_bitsPerSample / 8);

    if (interleaved) {
        for (size_t i{ posInCache }; ...) {
            for (auto ch: channels) {
                size_t cho{...}; 
                result.emplace_back(convert_sample(&m_data[i + cho], sample_len);
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (auto ch: channels) {
            for (size_t i{ posInCache }; ...) {
                size_t cho{...}; 
                result.emplace_back(convert_sample(&m_data[i + cho], sample_len);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

## Avoid unnecessary floating point math

Don't write `(size_t)(m_cacheSize * 0.5)`, write `m_cacheSize / 2`. The answer should be the same, and if it isn't, it's because on 64-bit machines, a `double` has less precision than a `size_t`, and with large enough values this will become noticable. Also, it's quite costly to convert an integer to a `double` and back; not only do you waste some CPU cycles converting between the two, it might cause an interrupt where the operating system has to restore the FPU state after a lazy FPU context switch (not really an issue in your code since you already convert samples to `float` in `samples()`, but just so you know).

## Don't create throwaway threads

I was wondering why you needed locking at all, but then I spotted this in `audio()`:

```
std::thread extendBuffer{ &Waveread::load,this,m_cachePos + (size_t)(m_cacheSize * 0.5), m_cacheSize };
extendBuffer.detach();
```

You are creating threads here, but don't care what they are doing and detaching them immediately. But what if I am calling `audio()` in quick succession, with `startSample()` wildly varying at each call? Maybe there are two threads that want to read audio from different places, and they each call `load()` in turn? If reading data from disk was really so slow that you need the caching, then this will potentially create a large amount of threads that are slowing down the system, and potentially causing the wrong data being in the cache at the time it will be used. It is in fact possible that you create a thread to extend the buffer, but it will not start immediately, and then immediately there is another call to `audio()`, which will hit case 1 or case 3, which will call `load()`, and then between that call to `load()` and the call to `samples()`, the background thread will execute its `load()`. That means `samples()` will read from the wrong data.

It's hard to reason about threads you no longer have any control over. I would just trust the operating system, it already performs caching for you, and will likely read ahead for you as well.

## Avoid using a `std::set` for `channels`

A `std::set` is quite an expensive data structure to use to pass the desired `channels` to `audio()`: it allocates memory on the heap and builds a balanced tree of nodes. Furthermore, you pass it by value so a copy has to be made. A better datastructure would be a [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset), but unfortunately it needs to know its size up front, and since WAV files support up to 65535 channels, that is not great. Another option would be a [`std::vector<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool). Be sure to pass these structures by `const` reference:

```
std::vector<float> audio(
    size_t startSample, 
    size_t sampleCount, 
    const std::vector<bool> &channels = {true, true},
    size_t stride = 0u, 
    bool interleaved = true
) {
    ...
}
```

To iterate over them, you would do something like:

```
for (size_t ch = 0; ch < channels.size(); ++ch) {
    if (channels[ch]) {
        size_t cho{ (ch % ...) };
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice review!  having a competition in the monthly ranks xD

Comment: Thank you this is really good stuff. The most humbling thing is realising that the OS does probably make caching redundant. I'll benchmark and then implement the advice.

Answer (score 2):

**`WAV_HEADER`:**

```
bool read(std::istream& s)
{
    if (s.good())
    {
        s.seekg(0u);
        s.read(&m_0_headerChunkID[0], 4);
        s.read((char*)&m_4_chunkSize, 4);
        s.read(&m_8_format[0], 4);
        s.read(&m_12_subchunk1ID[0], 4);
        s.read((char*)&m_16_subchunk1Size, 4);
        s.read((char*)&m_20_audioFormat, 2);
        s.read((char*)&m_22_numChannels, 2);
        s.read((char*)&m_24_sampleRate, 4);
        s.read((char*)&m_28_byteRate, 4);
        s.read((char*)&m_32_bytesPerBlock, 2);
        s.read((char*)&m_34_bitsPerSample, 2);
        s.read(&m_36_dataSubchunkID[0], 4);
        s.read((char*)&m_40_dataSubchunkSize, 4);
    }
    return s.good();
}
```

Hmm. It would be more conventional to make this an `istream& operator>>(istream&, WAV_HEADER& header);`

I don't think we need to check if the stream is `good()` before reading. We just do the read, and let the stream handle the errors (it'll set failbit or throw if necessary).

Seeking to the start of the stream inside this function may cause problems in some cases (e.g. a wave file embedded in a larger file). It is probably better to require that the input stream is positioned at the start of the wave format when passed in to the reader.

---

```
void clear() { ... }
```

This should probably just be the class constructor.

---

**`Waveread`:**

```
Waveread(
    std::unique_ptr<std::istream>&& stream,
    size_t cacheSize = 1048576u,
    double cacheExtensionThreshold = 0.5
)
    :
    m_stream{ stream.release() },
    m_header{},
    m_data{},
    m_dataMutex{},
    m_cachePos{ 0u },
    m_opened{ false },
    m_cacheSize{ cacheSize }, // 1MB == 1048576u
    m_cacheExtensionThreshold{ cacheExtensionThreshold }
{
    if (m_cacheExtensionThreshold < 0.0)
        m_cacheExtensionThreshold = 0.0;
    else if (m_cacheExtensionThreshold > 1.0)
        m_cacheExtensionThreshold = 1.0;

    m_header.clear();
}
```

While it might be safer to take the stream as a `unique_ptr`, it is a fiddle for the user compared to taking a reference to the stream. (Either is fine... just something to consider).

We could take the `std::unique_ptr<>` by value (there's no need to require the r-value reference) and `std::move` it into `m_stream`. (These are really just semantic differences though).

With C++17 we can do `m_cacheExtensionThreshold{ std::clamp(cacheExtensionThreshold, 0.0, 1.0) }`. Without it, we might define our own `clamp` utility function for neatness.

Having to call `m_header.clear()` here as a separate step again suggests making it the `WAV_HEADER` constructor.

---

```
Waveread(Waveread&& other) noexcept
```

Consider supporting move assignment, since we have move construction.

---

```
void reset(std::unique_ptr<std::istream>&& stream)
```

If we support move assignment, we don't need this function, as we could do something like: `oldWaveRead = Waveread(std::move(newStream));`

---

```
bool open()
{
    if (!m_opened)
    {
        m_header.read(*m_stream.operator->());
        if (m_header.valid())
        {
            m_opened = true;
            load(0u, m_cacheSize);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false; // we couldn't open it
    }
    return true; // we didn't open it, but it was already opened.
}
```

Returning as early as possible may make code like this easier to read, since the `if` branches end immediately, and we don't need the `else` clauses:

```
bool open()
{
    if (m_opened)
        return true; // already open
    
    m_header.read(*m_stream.operator->());

    if (!m_header.valid())
        return false; // couldn't open it
    
    m_opened = true;
    load(0u, m_cacheSize);

    return true;
}
```

---

```
const size_t& cacheSize() const { return m_cacheSize; }
//! Get start position of cache
const size_t& cachePos() const { return m_cachePos; }
//! Has the file been opened
const bool& opened() const { return m_opened; }
//! Get cache extension threshold: this is the fraction of the cache that is read before it is extended.
const double& cacheExtensionThreshold() const { return m_cacheExtensionThreshold; }
```

It is likely faster (and a little safer) to return these POD types by value, instead of by reference.

---

```
void setCacheExtensionThreshold(const double& cacheExtensionThreshold)
void setCacheSize(const size_t& csize)
```

Similarly, these arguments should be passed by value.

---

Unfortunately I don't have time to continue for now...

Overall I think it would be neater if the caching of the data were entirely separate from the processing of the wave file format. Perhaps we could have some sort of `istream_caching_iterator{ stream, cache_size };` that reads from the stream into a buffer. Then the wave reader requests the data it needs to, when it needs it, without caring about the buffering itself.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
            s.read(&m_0_headerChunkID[0], 4);
            s.read((char*)&m_4_chunkSize, 4);
            s.read(&m_8_format[0], 4);
            s.read(&m_12_subchunk1ID[0], 4);
            s.read((char*)&m_16_subchunk1Size, 4);
            s.read((char*)&m_20_audioFormat, 2);
            s.read((char*)&m_22_numChannels, 2);
            s.read((char*)&m_24_sampleRate, 4);
            s.read((char*)&m_28_byteRate, 4);
            s.read((char*)&m_32_bytesPerBlock, 2);
            s.read((char*)&m_34_bitsPerSample, 2);
            s.read(&m_36_dataSubchunkID[0], 4);
            s.read((char*)&m_40_dataSubchunkSize, 4);
```

You're assuming endianness.

Comment: is this supposed to be a review?

Comment: @AryanParekh yes.

Comment: While you are technically correct that endianness is assumed in this code, I would argue that this is a non-issue; there are hardly any CPU architectures in use anymore that are big-endian, and in the posted code, `valid()` will actually return `false` if the code is compiled for big-endian and a little-endian file is read.